# Парсинг отправки команд

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется отправлять команды устройству и принимать ответ. Команды записываются в текст бокс в формате "Команда"+"/n" по /n определяю что это одна команда но возможно пользователь будет вбивать команды от руки тогда /n работает 
Как правильно розпарсить?

```
if (printer.CheckConnection()) {
    int start = 0;
    int and = 0;
    CString str = CommandSendTB->Text;
    CString Command;
    byte * vvv = new byte[100];

    richTextBox1->Clear();

    int temp;
    int count = 0;
    int countN = CommandSendTB->Lines->Length - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < CommandSendTB->Text->Length; i++) {
        if (str[i] == (CString)"<") {
            start = i + 1;
        }
        if (str[i] == (CString)">") {
            and = i - start;
            Command = str.Mid(start, and);
            temp = _ttoi(static_cast<LPCTSTR>(Command));
            vvv[count] = temp;
            count++;
        }

        if (str[i] == (CString)"\n") {
            printer.SendComand(vvv);

            for (int k = 0; k < sizeof(sim); k++) {
                if (sim[k] != 0) {
                    int l = int(sim[k]);
                    richTextBox1->Text += l + "\n";
                }
            }
            count = 0;
            memset(vvv, 0, sizeof(vvv));
        }
    }
}
else
    FalseConnection();
```